# Get return type with reflect-metadata , when return type is Promise of something

Tags: typescript, reflect-metadata

When function return type is `Promise<number>` , how can i get it with reflection?

If i just do

```
Reflect.getMetadata("design:returntype", target, key)
```

it's return just `Promise`, so there is a way to know that is Promise of number?

```
name:"Promise"
prototype:Promise {constructor: , then: , catch: , …}
reject:function reject() { … }
resolve:function resolve() { … }
```

Comment: I have the same question. :-/

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this feature will not be supported in the near future.

> As noted in [#14971 (comment)](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14971#issuecomment-297580549), reflection and runtime type serialization is outside the scope of the TypeScript project in the time being.
>
> — [Mohamed Hegazy](https://github.com/mhegazy)
>   ([link](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12577#issuecomment-297770330))

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Custom Method Decorator ?

/* Important Notes

- all type passed in the Decorator must be class
- interface & enum are not supported
  */

(TypeScript)

```
export function ReturnType(type: any): MethodDecorator {
  return (target, propertyKey) => {
    Reflect.defineMetaData('YOUR_CUSTOM_KEY', type, target, propertyKey);
  }
}

// Somewhere in your code

@ReturnType(Number)
async function myFunc():Promise<number> {
  return await Promise.resolve(1234)
}
```